# My Bevel Modifier isn't applying correctly

Tags: modifiers, bevel, mirror-modifier

I'm having a problem where when I apply my Bevel Modifier, this extra bevel appears in the middle of the mesh. The mesh is mirrored which would explain the extra bevel. The only problem is that prior to applying it, the bevel didn't appear, giving me the illusion that there was no problem. And I added clipping when mirroring the mesh so there isn't a noticeable gap (I doubled check).

Here's a gif that best explains my situation.

[image]

Here's the Blender File

[image]

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have internal faces across the edge of the mirror. Go into <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode then <kbd>Shift-Z</kbd> for <kbd>X-ray</kbd> mode.
[image]

Select and delete the faces with <kbd>X</kbd> > delete <kbd>Only Faces</kbd> and you can then apply the bevel without problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your mirror modifier merges the vertices at the mirror plane. The bevel modifier being after the mirror, it only sees coplanar faces there, so nothing happens.

But when you apply the bevel modifier, it applies it to the base mesh, ignoring the mirror. And there the geometry is different, hence the result is different.